# How to remotely execute a Postgres SQL function on Postgres using PySpark JDBC connector?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to execute the following query on a remote Postgres server from a PySpark application using the [JDBC connector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc):

```sql
SELECT id, postgres_function(some_column) FROM my_database GROUP BY id
```

The problem is I can't execute this kind of query on Pyspark using `spark.sql(QUERY)`, obviously because the `postgres_function` is not an ANSI SQL function [supported since Spark 2.0.0](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#sql).

I'm using Spark 2.0.1 and Postgres 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have is to use subquery:

```
table = """
  (SELECT id, postgres_function(some_column) FROM my_database GROUP BY id) AS t
"""
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table=table)
```

but this will execute a whole query, including aggregation, on the database side and fetch the result.

In general it doesn't matter if function is an ANSI SQL function or if it has an equivalent in the source database and ll functions called in `spark.sql` are executed in Spark after data is fetched.