# how to use nextval() in a postgres jdbc driver for pyspark?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I have a table named "mytable" in Postgres with two columns, id (bigint) and value (varchar(255)).

id gets its value from a sequence using `nextval('my_sequence')`.

A PySpark application takes a dataframe and uses the Postgres JDBC jar (postgresql-42.1.4.jar) to insert the dataframe into "mytable".  I'm creating the id column using:

```
df.withColumn('id', lit("nextval('my_sequence')"))
```

Postgres is interpreting the column as a 'varying character'.

I can see that there are ways for calling Postgres methods when reading data ([How to remotely execute a Postgres SQL function on Postgres using PySpark JDBC connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806488/how-to-remotely-execute-a-postgres-sql-function-on-postgres-using-pyspark-jdbc-c)), but I'm not sure how to call a Postgres function like `nextval()` for writing data to Postgres.

Here's how I am currently writing the data from Pyspark to Postgres:

```py
df.write.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", 'mytable') \
    .mode('append') \
    .save()
```

How can one write to a Postgres table using PySpark when one column needs a sequence number using `nextval()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You cannot execute database code on insert unless you create your own `JdbcDialect` and override insert logic. I reckon it is not something you want to do for such a small feature.

Personally I would use trigger:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION set_id() RETURNS trigger AS $set_id$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
      NEW.id = nextval('my_sequence');
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$set_id$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_id BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_id();
```

and leave the rest of the job to the database server.

```py
df.select(lit(null).cast("bigint").alias("id"), col("value")).write
    ...
```

You could also use `monotonically_increasing_id` ([Primary keys with Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33102727/6910411)) and just shift values according to the largest id in the database, but it might be brittle.

Comment: Now I would need the particular id per each of the rows which the database assigned. Is there a simple way to get it?

Comment: @SimeonKredatus Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hey, thanks for a prompt reaction. Let's say I define a schema as follows: schema = StructType( [ StructField("id", IntegerType(), True), StructField("property1", IntegerType(), True)]), then I do some crunching and store it to database as follows: frame.write.option('mergeSchema', 'true').jdbc(url=url, table=table, mode='append', properties=properties). I do have a trigger in a database as you proposed, meaning DB assigns ID. Now I would need to fetch that id for each row, preferably without doing the select. Is there an easy way of getting that out without running a select?

Comment: The other option for my usecase is to compute a unique hash for each row and manage it out of database - meaning spark would always fill the database column, yet I would still prefer to have postgres in charge of the ID sequence. Once my spark job persists the dataset I would need it to emit a kafka event with the assigned id.

Comment: @SimeonKredatus So you wan to have cake an eat it too. You generate unique ID on Spark itself (see for example implementation of [MongoDB ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)). With PostgreSQL specific solution, you could listen to events there with `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY`, and propagate to Kafka directly.